# How to delete all lines and words from a text file up until a certain point

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text-files

The problem I have is that I have a text file which contains a whole load of rubbish and just at the bottom are a few lines which holds the information I need. I want to be able to delete all the rubbish and just keep the useful information.

Iam hoping i can attach the text file which can explain it better.

There is a specific post which is relevant to this post that I am doing, however I have followed it and it hasn’t solved the problem I have. I have tried arrays and many other things, it just hasn’t worked.

it has information like this in it

```
|83Ïú¯–ŸªÖ!
```

just at the bottom of the text file it has this

```
000---------
```

i want to keep everything after the 000 and the rest of it i want to remove.

Comment: Create a new file with only the lines you want.

Comment: That doesn't look like a text file, but rather a binary file with some text inside it. You need to know the format of the binary file to be able to read and parse it, and then it should be simple to extract the information you want from the file.

Comment: Hi i double checked with a friend and the text file given to me was actually a text file from a video. he basically turned the video into a text file and wants to get the data at the bottom of it. hope this makes it easier to understand the problem im having.

Comment: @VijayYadav Did you try the approach I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the original file for reading.
  `std::ifstream fin(orig_filename, std::ios::binary);`
- Open a new temporary file for writing in the same directory
  `std::ofstream fout(temp_filename, std::ios::binary);`
- Search for the marker pattern in the original file:

```
    std::string marker = "000---------";
    auto it =
        std::search(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), marker.begin(), marker.end());
```

- Copy the rest from `fin` to `fout` (if the pattern was found):

```
    if(it == std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()) {
        std::cout << "pattern " << marker << " not found\n";
    } else {
        // the iterator "it" is now at the last char in the marker pattern,
        // step over it and copy the rest to fout
        std::copy(++it, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                  std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(fout));
    }
```

- Rename the temporary file to the same name as the original file:
  `std::rename(temp_filename, orig_filename);`

Note: Opening the files in `std::ios::binary` mode is afaik only needed on Windows.